# Django format DecimalField in query / annotation

Tags: django, aggregate, django-queryset

Is it possible to format a `DecimalField` in an annotation similar to [`intcomma`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma) template tag?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    plu = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=D('0'))
```

For example if `instance.price = Decimal('1000')` the annotated attribute would return the number formatted with a comma separator (`1,000.00`)

I'm creating PDF reports in ReportLab and table data is a list of lists. If the queryset could return the comma separated number there would be speed improvements rather than having to iterate over each object in the queryset to apply the formatting.

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma

products = Product.objects.all()
table_data = [['PLU', 'Description', 'Price']]
for product in products:
    table_data.append([product.plu, product.description, intcomma(product.price)])
```

Could be simplified to

```
table_data = [['PLU', 'Description', 'Price']] + list(
    Product.objects.all()
    .annotate(comma_sep_price=...)
    .values_list('plu', 'descripton', 'comma_sep_price')
)
```

Comment: Exactly why would you do that? Django models should *store* / *retrieve* data, not format data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I use reportlab to create reports and comma separated numbers improve readability. Since table data in reportlab is a list of lists I could make speed improvements by generating the desired output using `.values_list()` rather than having to loop over the queryset, apply the formatting, and append to a new list.

Comment: You could try to create a custom field that by default returns the value formatted, but I wouldn't do that. Maybe `map(lambda (plu, description, comma_sep_price) : (plu, description, intcomma(comma_sep_price)),  Product.objects.all()
    .annotate(comma_sep_price=...)
    .values_list('plu', 'descripton', 'comma_sep_price'))` is useful compromise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the [PostgreSQL data type formatting function `TO_CHAR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-formatting.html).

Using an [`ExpressionWrapper`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import CharField, ExpressionWrapper, Func, F, Value

data = (
    Product.objects
    .annotate(
        formatted_price=ExpressionWrapper(
            Func(F('price'), Value('FM999,999,999.00'), function='TO_CHAR'),
            output_field=CharField()
        )
    )
    .values_list('plu', 'description', 'formatted_price')
)
```

Or as a reusable [custom query expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#writing-your-own-query-expressions):

```
class CommaSeparated(Func):
    function = 'TO_CHAR'
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s, 'FM999,999,999.00')"

data = (
    Product.objects
    .annotate(formatted_price=CommaSeparated(F('price'), output_field=CharField()))
    .values('plu', 'description', 'formatted_price')
)
```